# How to stop errors from showing on web pages, show on pop up instead?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, modalpopupextender

i am developing this app which is going to be a template in my organization, but there is a problem i need to solve. I want to show errors on an AjaxControlTookit's modalpop and never let it show that ugly yellow text on the browser with stacktrace.

WHERE should i intercept and WHAT should i intercept for this to work?

Is there an lifecycle event i can use that happens before rendering but after the page is itself contructed (and thus the error has happened?) at that event, will i have the page controls ready? Assuming i have a masterpage and the modalpopup will be there, could i do this general error handling in the masterpage?

Is this something i need to use global.asax? (i have never used it, but with a name like that and the events it has, i can figure what it does)

Is this something doable even? could i catch every exception, even browser errors that happened related to my pages?

Edit:

My problem isn't really with what the user sees, is that i don't want the browser to display the stack trace and the yellow error page, destroying anything the user has done so far. 
I want to create a nice and clean user experience and if the user can recover from whatever issue is causing the exception i want them to have the option, which include not destroying the page they had before the post-back. Is that understandable or i am unable to explain this any better?

Comment: Showing server-side errors with JavaScript seems to be a _very_ unreliable option to me.

Comment: Better use [the `customError` element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc(v=vs.85).aspx) in the web.config file to control what the end-user sees.

Comment: My problem isnt really with what the user sees, is that i dont want the browser to display the stacktrace and the yellow error page, destroying anything the user has done so far. Is that understandable?

Answer (score 0):

You could easily do this using javaScript:

```
window.onerror = function(msg, url, linenumber) {
    alert('Error message: '+msg+'\nURL: '+url+'\nLine Number: '+linenumber);
    return true;
}
```

http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/error2.shtml

Comment: I want specifically a modalpopup, not just an alert. besides, suppose an exception happened on the serverside, where should i try this? which file/class/object?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, here is a link on how to handle errors (including global errors) in ASP.NET:

[How to: Display Safe Error Messages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994a1482.ASPX)

Then with regards to the modalpopup, in the samples mentioned in the link, the user was redirected to some other error page. You can pass the error messages to that error page and then display the modelpopup on that error page.